# Databinder.Eval not showing all data

Tags: asp.net, ascx

My markup:
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "summary")%>

Running that to view the data from summary which was retrieved on a web form. When you get the email with the data, it shows everything, but if you view the submitted form on the webpage it cuts it off.

Any idea how I can get it to show the full information. Thank you.

Ps. Its in a ascx file.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are probably missing quotes around the value in your input. You need something like this in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="summary" value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "summary")%>" />
```

Without quotes, the value will be indeed cut on the first space.

Comment: @Dylan where exactly is it being "cut off"? You can wrap code in comments with backtick (`).

Comment: I'm struggling to get the code formatted in the comment system... So sorry. but Lets say the summary is really long , 1000 words or something like that, it doesnt even make it to the first 100 words, just randomly cuts it off..

Heres is the code to get the data in the form.

`<asp:textbox id="txtSummary" runat="server"  cssclass="NormalTextBox" width="500" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6"></asp:textbox>`

Comment: I believe its capturing it correctly, because when I get the email with the data, its all there, but when I look on the website for submission (database type thing) it only shows a small part of it before getting cut off. Which is the first code I posted.

And it's not getting cut on the first space, its just a random cut off, there are tons of spaces before hand that it's not cutting off

Comment: I counted the characters and its 255 limit. Not sure where that setting would be to change that.

Comment: Sounds like the database field can contain only 255 characters then.